# How to use Regex in SQL for extracting values after repetitive numbers

Tags: sql, regex

I have the following table (`table1`):

```
+---+---------------------------------------------+
+---|--------att1 --------------------------------+
| 1 | 10.2.5.4 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa               |
| 2 | asd 100.99.98.97 97.3.2.1.a.b.c fsdf        |
| 3 | fd 95.94.93.92 92.5.7.1.a.b.c               |
| 4 | a 11.4.99.75 75.77.52.41.in-addr.arpa       |
+---+---------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to get the following values (that are located after the repetitive numbers): `in-addr.arpa, a.b.c, a.b.c, in-addr.arpa`.
I tried to use the following format with no success:

```
SELECT att1 
FROM table1 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(att1 , '^(\d+?)\1$')
```

I would like it to run in Impala and Oracle.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It is not clear which part of the string you want to extract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303) (assuming you are using an Oracle DB).

```
select regexp_substr(att1,'[0-9]\.([^0-9]+)',1,1,null,1)
from table1
```

- `[0-9]\.` a numeric followed by a `.`
- `[^0-9]+` any character other than a numeric is matched until the next numeric is found. `()` around this indicates the group (first in this case) and we only extract that part of the string.

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/JKO75157)

Comment: Thanks a lot @vkp, do you know what is the equivalent to REGEXP_SUBSTR in impala?

Comment: `regexp_extract`? i see it in the documentation but can't be sure if your version has it.